# Scrollbar does not appear when programmatically adding columns to listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scrollbar

When I add additional columns to the `listview` control that go beyond the width of the control, it does not show the horizontal scrollbar. 
It will only show the scrollbar if the size (resize event) of the `listview` is changed. How can I make it display the scrollbar right after adding the columns?

I tried `refresh()` and setting `scrollable = false,` then `scrollable = true,` but none of that worked. I'd prefer a solution without DllImports.

Comment: I think it's default to show scroll bar. Anyway try by enabling it with listView.Scrollable = true;

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say scrollable, not scrollbars above.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug to me. But your question contains the workaround to trick the `ListView` into showing the `Scrollbar`:

```
listView1.SuspendLayout();
listView1.Columns.Add(..);
// ..
listView1.Width -= 1; ;
listView1.Width += 1; ;
listView1.ResumeLayout();
```